# What is this #define using multiple uninitialized arrays in one header file?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have seen the following code being used in one header file from cyanogenmod (changed names to improve readability):

```
#define THIS_C \
const char CP::a[] = "a"; \
const char CP::b[] = "b"; \

#define THIS_H \
static const char a[]; \
static const char b[]; \
```

How does this work and how can I use this kind of #define statements?

Also how is it possible that the compiler is ok with creating arrays without initializing the variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "this kind" of `#define` statement? What do you see in these statements that make them different from other `#define` statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does this work

Macros work by replacing the macro with its definition.

If you write this in a source file:

```
THIS_C
```

The pre-processor will replace it with:

```
const char CP::a[] = "a";
const char CP::b[] = "b";
```

> and how can I use it?

Well, if you want declare such variables, then you can use the macro to generate those declarations. In this trivial example it is however unclear what - if any - advantage there is to use the macro instead of writing the declarations directly. The macro might just serve to obfuscate the code, which would be undesirable.

---

> Also how is it possible that the compiler is ok with creating arrays without initializing the variable?

Within the context of a class definition, `THIS_H` would be an extern declaration of two array static members. Such declaration does not need to specify the size of the array nor may it initialise the variable. The initialisation is in the definition (which I suppose is what `THIS_C` expands to).